# can't run shell on emacs for osx

Tags: osx, shell

When I run `M-x shell`, I see the following warning (and no shell):

> Process shell exited abnormally with code 127

I freshly installed emacs v. 28.2 for osx.  I put my stuff in my .emacs file, but I don't think this is causing the problem, as I've tried removing all its contents and I still have this issue.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs isn’t doing anything wrong, it’s just telling you that it ran your shell and the shell exited with an error code. You should read your shell’s documentation to find out what that error code means; it may indicate a problem that you can fix.

Comment: Is there a way I can check where it is looking for my shell application?  I can use my shell outside of emacs without problems, so it seems it must be pointing to the wrong location

Comment: It’s generally specified in `shell-file-name`, but see the help for `shell` for more information (`C-h f shell <RET>`).

Comment: Have you tried `M-x term` ?

Comment: @DavidJ.: So have you checked the exit code 127 of your shell? If you run Bash, try `info bash`; for other shells, either see its official website or Google it. All in all, you need to know the meaning of the exit code first.